# Windows command to exclude all directories and files starting with a dot (period)

Tags: windows, command-line

On my filesystem some directory names start with a dot like `.plugin` or `.metadata` and some files also start with a dot like `.mydata`.

Is there a Windows command whereby I can use only the non dot files?

Comment: Are you referring to when you are _searching_ for files?

Comment: EXCEPT is built into Take Command for Windows (the successor to 4DOS).  That implies to me that no such software by Microsoft did the same thing when JP Software built in that internal command.  If there is a slick way to do so with newer versions of Windows using just built-in software, PowerShell would be the most likely candidate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean exclude them from Explorer's view.

To do this, cd to the directory you want to work on, and run 
`attrib /s /d +H .*`

That will make all the files and folders in the directory and all subdirectories Hidden, but leave the files that don't start with . visible.

you can reverse the change with:
`attrib /s /d -H .*`